# PHP count line/row on text file based on value column

Tags: php

Continuing on my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52397274/php-count-text-file-rows-based-on-date-and-time).

I have text log file called reject. You can see it [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ptp9jas8s1he9hh/Reject.txt?dl=0)

As you can see there are 4 steps on tab called:

```
1. Battery level
2. Piezo sound level
3. Left D3  (Ch 3) light intensity
4. Right D2  (Ch 1) light intensity
```

[image]

Now I want to count every row with condition:

```
Which column(Steps) value is filled then count it.
Example: on row 1, We can see the value 0 (any value) is on step Piezo sound level. Then count it.
```

So finally I can know how many quantity Reject Process.

```
Battery level = x quantity
Piezo sound level = x quantity
Left D3  (Ch 3) light intensity = x quantity
Right D2  (Ch 1) light intensity = x quantity
```

The PHP Code:

```
$fromDateTime = new DateTime('Wed, Sep 19  2018 08:00:00');
$toDateTime = new DateTime('Wed, Sep 19  2018 19:59:00');
$file = file_get_contents('reject.txt');
$lines = explode("\n",$file);

// counter
$rowsintimespan = 0;

// Do Line-By-Line starting by Line 16 (Array Index 15)
for($i = 15; $i < count($lines); $i++) {
// if the file is "Tue, Sep 18<tab>2018<tab>23:59:53<tab>"
$dateobj = DateTime::createFromFormat("???,?M?d??Y?H:i:s+", $lines[$i]);

// check if date is in your Timespan
if($dateobj < $toDateTime && $dateobj > $fromDateTime) {
        $rowsintimespan++; // count if in timespan
    }
}

// Debug-Output
echo $rowsintimespan;
```

UPDATE

I need to read the last column value, Example: if the value of row is on column Left D3 then count it. If the value of row is on column Piezo then count it.

[image]

Comment: So you only want to count the last value of a row? I.e. if batterylevel and piezo are set, only count piezo? If Battery, piezo and left are set, then just count left?

Comment: Yes... exactly Sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you're ok with writing down your columns as keys then this should work as you described:

```
$fromDateTime = new DateTime('Wed, Sep 19  2018 08:00:00');
$toDateTime = new DateTime('Wed, Sep 19  2018 19:59:00');
$file = file_get_contents('Reject.txt');
$lines = explode("\n", $file);

// counter
$rowsintimespan = 0;
// keys should correspond to columns
$keys = [
    'date',
    'time',
    'battery',
    'piezo',
    'leftD3',
    'rightD2'
];

$values = array_fill(0, count($keys), 0);
$values = array_combine($keys, $values);

// Do Line-By-Line starting by Line 16 (Array Index 15)
for ($i = 11; $i < count($lines); $i++) {
    // if the file is "Tue, Sep 18<tab>2018<tab>23:59:53<tab>"
    $dateobj = DateTime::createFromFormat("???,?M?d??Y?H:i:s+", $lines[$i]);

    // check if date is in your Timespan
    if ($dateobj < $toDateTime && $dateobj > $fromDateTime) {
        $rowsintimespan++; // count if in timespan

        // get line elements
        $lineContent = explode("\t", $lines[$i]);

        // loop through line elements and count them
        $x = 0;
        for ($j = 0; $j < count($keys); $j++) {
            if (!isset($lineContent[$j])) {
                continue;
            }

            // remember position of last not empty column
            if (trim($lineContent[$j]) != '') {
                $x = $j;
            }
        }

        if ($x > 0) {
            $values[$keys[$x]]++;
        }
    }
}

// Debug-Output
echo $rowsintimespan;

// Output every column
echo '<pre>';
print_r($values);
```

This will print out:

```
Array
(
    [date] => 0
    [time] => 0
    [battery] => 4
    [piezo] => 31
    [leftD3] => 17
    [rightD2] => 1
)
```

Comment: Hi Alex, I got error `Notice: Undefined index: date in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\test.php on line 39

Notice: Undefined index: time in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\test.php on line 39

Notice: Undefined index: battery in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\test.php on line 39

Notice: Undefined index: piezo in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\test.php on line 39

Notice: Undefined index: leftD3 in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\test.php on line 39

Notice: Undefined index: rightD2 in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\test.php on line 39`

Comment: Sorry, Dave, I had error_reporting off, I edited the code to avoid notices

Comment: Hi Alex, I tried to count manually, the only 1 correct is Right D2 = 1, another is wrong. Here is my manually count to log file: `Battery: 5
Right D2: 1
Left D3: 27
Piezo: 52
`

Comment: @HiDayurieDave I finally understood what you asked for. Try this updated code

Comment: Hi Alex, just now checked only `Right D2` is correct. Another is wrong. Should be `Battery: 5 Right D2: 1 Left D3: 26 Piezo: 52`

Comment: It is so, if you remove the condition that checks $fromDateTime and $toDateTime

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180423/discussion-between-hidayurie-dave-and-aleksandras-gavinciuk).

Comment: Hi Alex, I have an question, Please go to our chat.

Comment: Hi Alek, another question. As you can see on array if there is `[date] => 1`. How to count exclude `[date]` ?

Comment: I have trouble when I remove this `[date] => 0` and `[time] => 0`. The count is not correct anymore. On log file can we ignore Date and Time tab? Please advice sir

Comment: Hi Alek, I got another issue. Please refer to this new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53890560/php-count-row-from-text-file-based-on-after-specific-tab need your advice please

Comment: Hi Alex, I got new question still regarding this. Kindly need your advice please, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54376905/php-read-specific-tab-row-column-and-set-it-on-loop

Comment: Hi Alek, if you free kindly please advice

Answer (score 0):

Just split your row by your tabs and check for !empty();

```
//Set Time-Span
$fromDateTime = new DateTime('Wed, Sep 19  2018 00:00:00');
$toDateTime = new DateTime('Wed, Sep 19  2018 17:00:00');

// Load File
$file = file_get_contents('Reject.txt');

// Split by lines
$lines = explode("\n",$file);

// counter
$rowsintimespan = 0;
$rowswithbattery = 0;

// Do Line-By-Line starting by Line 16 (Array Index 15)
for($i = 15; $i < count($lines); $i++) {
    // if the file is "Tue,<space>Sep<space>18<space><space>2018<tab>23:59:53<tab>"
    $dateobj = DateTime::createFromFormat("???, M  d?Y?H:i:s+", $lines[$i]);

    // check if date is in your Timespan
    if($dateobj < $toDateTime && $dateobj > $fromDateTime) {
        $rowsintimespan++; // count if in timespan
        $cols = explode("\t",$lines[$i]);
        // 0 = Date, 1 = Time, 2 = Battery Level, 3 = Piezo, 4 = left, 5 = Right
        // Count Battery-Values
        if (!empty($cols[2])) {
            $rowswithbattery++;
        }
    }
}

// Debug-Output
echo 'In Timespan: '.$rowsintimespan."\n";
echo 'Rows With Battery: '.$rowswithbattery
```

Produces:

```
In Timespan: 84
Rows With Battery: 84
```

Full Example with all your columns: https://ideone.com/VAQH7h

Also you could iterate over every header and create a neat array as I showed in https://ideone.com/YUU1jP

```
// Split by lines
$lines = explode("\n", $file);
$header = explode("\t", $lines[9]);
// counter
$rowsintimespan = 0;
$counter = Array();

// Create an entry for every header and trim it to lose additional whitespaces
foreach($header as $index => $head){
    $counter[rtrim($head)] = 0;
}

// Do Line-By-Line starting by Line 16 (Array Index 15)
for($i = 11; $i < count($lines); $i++) {
    // the file is "Tue,<space>Sep<space>18<space><space>2018<tab>23:59:53<tab>"
    $dateobj = DateTime::createFromFormat("???, M d  Y?H:i:s+", $lines[$i]);
    // check if date is in your Timespan
    if($dateobj < $toDateTime && $dateobj > $fromDateTime) {
        $rowsintimespan++; // count if in timespan
        $cols = explode("\t",$lines[$i]);
        // 0 = Date, 1 = Time, 2 = Battery Level, 3 = Piezo, 4 = left, 5 = Right
        // Count Battery-Values
        foreach($header as $index => $head){
            // For every header check if col is empty
            $counter[rtrim($head)] += empty($cols[$index]) ? 0 : 1;
        }
    }
}

// Debug-Output
echo 'In Timespan: '.$rowsintimespan."\n";
var_dump($counter);
```

**Update to match the updated question:**

Then just do some simple math.

Theory: if you have 80 set columns with battery, and 20 with set piezo, you can substract the 20 piezo counter from your 80 battery counter and then you know how many last battery-columns you have and how many last piezo columns.

Thus:

```
$lastwithright = $rowswithright;
$lastwithleft = $rowswithleft - $rowswithright;
$lastwithpiezo = $rowswithpiezo - $rowswithleft;
$lastwithbattery = $rowswithbattery - $rowswithpiezo;
```

Comment: Hi Bam, I'm updated my question above, please have a look

Comment: Tried and got the result is wrong, refer to the log file that I share.`lastwithright: 84
lastwithleft: -57
lastwithpiezo: 52
lastwithbattery: 5`

Comment: I try to manually count, the correct value should be: ` `Battery: 5
Right D2: 1
Left D3: 27
Piezo: 52
``

Comment: @Hidayurie Dave I don't think so, works perfectly: https://ideone.com/9HivaU I'm really wondering what you are doing. You have noticed that the snippet here is not complete, right? Habve you read, that the full code is on ideone? Because it works without modifcation.

Comment: Hi Bam, I just tried to use your code on ideone.com/9HivaU (I'm using your pure code) but still get the wrong value, `In Timespan: 84 Rows With Battery: 84 Rows With Piezo: 79 Rows With Left: 27 Rows With Rigth: 83 Rows ending with Right:83 Rows ending with Left:-56 Rows ending with Piezo:52 Rows ending with Battery:5`

Comment: Why is different on ideone.com/9HivaU  with my local test? I'm using your pure code btw