# PHP Oracle inserting data on loop got incorrect id

Tags: php, oracle, loops

I'm continuing my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52403677/php-count-line-row-on-text-file-based-on-value-column).

Now I need to insert the value to DB. But ID inserted is not correct as on my database master.

```
$qModel = oci_parse($c1, "SELECT MODELID, MODEL_NAME FROM WA_LFO_TBL_MODEL 
WHERE ACTIVE = 'Y'");
oci_execute($qModel);
while($dModel = oci_fetch_array($qModel))
{
    $qDtl2 = oci_parse($c1, "SELECT * FROM WA_LFO_TBL_MODEL_CONFIGURATION WHERE MODELID_FK = '" . $dModel['MODELID'] . "'");
    oci_execute($qDtl2);
    while($dDtl2 = oci_fetch_array($qDtl2))
    {
        $q = oci_parse($c1, "SELECT * FROM WA_LFO_TBL_REJECT_PROCESS WHERE MODELID_FK = '" . $dModel['MODELID'] . "' ORDER BY SORT_NO ASC");
        oci_execute($q);
        while($d = oci_fetch_array($q))
        {
            $idkeys[] = $d['RP_ID'];
            $keys[] = $d['RP_NAME'];
        }

        $values = array_fill(0, count($keys), 0);
        $values = array_combine($keys, $values);

        for($i = $readRowAfter; $i < count($linesReject); $i++)
        {
            // if the fileReject is "Tue, Sep 18<tab>2018<tab>23:59:53<tab>"
            $dateobjReject = DateTime::createFromFormat($createFromFormat, $linesReject[$i]);

            // check if date is in your Timespan
            if($dateobjReject < $toDateTime && $dateobjReject > $fromDateTime)
            {
                $rowsintimespanReject++; // count if in timespan

                $lineContent = explode("\t", $linesReject[$i]);

                // loop through line elements and count them
                $x = 0;
                for ($j = 0; $j < count($keys); $j++) {
                    if (!isset($lineContent[$j])) {
                        continue;
                    }

                    // remember position of last not empty column
                    if (trim($lineContent[$j]) != '') {
                        $x = $j;
                    }
                }

                if ($x > 0) {
                    $values[$keys[$x]]++;
                }
            }
        }

        $i = 0; 
        $sql = "";

        foreach ($values as $value)
        {
            if($value != 0)
            {
                $sql = oci_parse($c1,"INSERT INTO WA_LFO_TBL_REJECT_OUTPUT(MODELID_FK, QUANTITY, RPID_FK, CONFIGURATIONID_FK)VALUES('" . $dModel['MODELID'] . "', '" . $value . "', '" . $idkeys[$i] . "', '" . $dDtl2['CONFIGURATIONID'] . "')"); 
                oci_execute($sql);
            } 

            $i++; 
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see that I'm trying to insert the date on `foreach` function.

But inserted data for ID is not correct for `RPID_FK`.
I realize maybe something wrong with the code, tried to get the solution but still stuck on it.

Is something wrong on that code?

Comment: Iám pretty sure the modern Oracle database versions supports some kind of `INSERT INTO table <columns> SELECT (<columns>) FROM table` SQL syntax which also should support JOIN's so you can select from multiple tables.. What would make it alot more eazy..

Comment: @RaymondNijland let me know the example please