# PHP read specific tab row column and set it on loop

Tags: php

I'm using PHP to read data from text file.

Here is the [log data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/r1tvbssvr06i6kd/Accept_10039787_012619_Ts1.txt?dl=0).

and the PHP:

```
$fileAccept = file_get_contents("\\\\192.168.184.13\\Reports\\".$dModel['MODEL_NAME'].$source."\\Accept\\Accept_".$dDtl['MODEL_CODE']."_".$dateCode."_".$dDtl['TS_CODE'].".txt");

$linesAccept = explode("\n",$fileAccept);
$rowsintimespanAccept = 0;

for($i = $readRowAfter; $i < count($linesAccept); $i++)
{
    // if the fileAccept is "Tue, Sep 18<tab>2018<tab>23:59:53<tab>"
    $dateobjAccept = DateTime::createFromFormat($createFromFormat, $linesAccept[$i]);

    // check if date is in your Timespan
    if($dateobjAccept < $toDateTime && $dateobjAccept > $fromDateTime)
    {
        $rowsintimespanAccept++; // count if in timespan
    }
}

for($i = 0; $i < $rowsintimespanAccept; $i++)
{
    //I need get date time here for each
}
```

That code is working OK.

But now I want to get each date time from text file.

Any clue how to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this after your $fileAccept:

```
$linesAccept = explode("\n", $fileAccept);
$readRowAfter = 9;
$createFromFormat = 'D, M j  Y H:i:s';
$outputDateFormat = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';
$inTimespan = [];

for($i = $readRowAfter; $i < count($linesAccept); $i++)
{
    $lineData = explode("\t", $linesAccept[$i]);

    if (!isset($lineData[0]) || !isset($lineData[1])) {
        continue;
    }

    $dateString = $lineData[0] . " " . $lineData[1];

    $dateObj = DateTime::createFromFormat($createFromFormat, $dateString);

    // check if date is in your Timespan
    if($dateobjAccept < $toDateTime && $dateobjAccept > $fromDateTime)
    {
        $inTimespan[] = $dateObj->format($outputDateFormat);
    }
}

foreach ($inTimespan as $date) {
    echo $date;
    echo '<br/>';
}
```

The $createFromFormat = 'D, M j  Y H:i:s'; the **j** in this might be **d**, but we can't know right now, since you only gave double-digit days, so if it breaks in case first day is 01 - then change it to **d**

Answer (score 0):

Unless I have misunderstood then your requirement was to be able to capture portions of each line in the logfile and use that in some fashion? The easiest way ( perhaps ) would be to use `list` and `explode` as shown below..

```
$logfile='c:/temp/Accept_10039787_012619_Ts1.txt';

$lines=file( $logfile );

foreach( $lines as $index => $line ){
    if( $index >=10 ){
        if( !empty( $line ) ){

            /* explode the string on TAB, capture two elements of interest as variables */
            list( $date, $time, , , )=explode("\t",$line );

            /* create a DateTime object */
            $oDate=DateTime::createFromFormat('D, M j  Y H:i:s', sprintf('%s %s', $date, $time ) );

            /* do somethig with the DateTime object... */
            echo $oDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . '<br />';
        }
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
2019-01-26 00:00:09
2019-01-26 00:00:23
2019-01-26 00:00:37
2019-01-26 00:00:50
2019-01-26 00:01:04
2019-01-26 00:01:17
2019-01-26 00:35:33.... etc etc cont'd
```